# Is it possible to hide a section/ field in service console view vs normal application view?

Tags: page-layout

Looking to hide a section/ field in console view but should be visible in normal detail view. Is there a way to achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: not sure with configuration but you can create a inline vf page and you can show/hide content based on console or normal view.